# Find second largest number

Tags: c, math

Yes, there are loads of people have already discussed this problem but this one seems to be a bit extraordinary. Program should find the second largest number from the five ones entered by user. We cannot use neither `loops` nor `if` statements. Also cannot use `arrays` and `goto's`, but can use ternary operator. The sample of I/0 :

Input : `34 -52 87 -12 20` Output: `34`

Input : `-87 52 87 87 20` Output: `87`

As you see user can input two same numbers and program should be able to treat it this way. This is C programming.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(void)
{

    int i1, i2, i3, i4, i5;
    int max, second_max;

    scanf("%d %d %d %d %d", &i1, &i2, &i3, &i4, &i5);

    max = i1;
    max = (i2 > max) ? i2 : max;
    max = (i3 > max) ? i3 : max;
    max = (i4 > max) ? i4 : max;
    max = (i5 > max) ? i5 : max;

    second_max = i1;
    second_max = (i1 > second_max && i1 < max) ? i1 : second_max;
    second_max = (i2 > second_max && i2 < max) ? i2 : second_max;
    second_max = (i3 > second_max && i3 < max) ? i3 : second_max;
    second_max = (i4 > second_max && i4 < max) ? i4 : second_max;
    second_max = (i5 > second_max && i5 < max) ? i5 : second_max;




    printf("\nmax: %d", max);
    printf("\nsecond_max : %d", second_max);




    return 0;
}
```

Here i can find everything, when it comes to the second sample of output it fails. I have an experience of programming but cannot solve this problem since morning

Comment: Given that this is clearly a homework exercise (the only realistic circumstance in which you will be told not to use loops, `if`, or arrays) .....  What have you tried?   At minimum, show how you are reading the values.

Comment: Your code only works when the max and second max are distinct values.  In the second example, the entry 87 appears twice, and is both the max and the second ma.  That complicates the conditions.  Frankly, I'm not willing to put my brain cells through this exercise; the conditions on it are nasty and not realistic — if someone wants to write the code in a silly way (e.g. your tutor) that's fine; they may do as they please.  But leave me out of it.  I'm sorry you don't get the same freedom of action that I have; bad luck.  Rest assured you won't need to use the solution in the real world.

Comment: I know that it is completely weird situation, in real conditions i would solve this problem for several minutes, anyways thanks for respond

Comment: I don't see much of a difference to the other homeworks we've seen so far. If you encounter a value that's larger *or equal* to the current `max`, move `max` to `second_max` and put the new value into `max`. Don't even try to walk the set of numbers twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly, the problem is easy to solve if you can sort the numbers. So how do you sort the numbers using only ternary operators? The answer is known as a [sorting network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_network).

Here's what the code looks like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void swap( int *a, int *b )
{
    int x = *a <= *b ? *a : *b;
    int y = *a <= *b ? *b : *a;
    *a = x;
    *b = y;
}

int main( void )
{
    int a = 1, b = 9, c = 3, d = 8, e = 3;

    swap( &a, &b );
    swap( &c, &d );
    swap( &b, &e );
    swap( &a, &b );
    swap( &d, &e );
    swap( &a, &c );
    swap( &c, &d );
    swap( &b, &c );
    swap( &c, &d );

    printf( "%d %d %d %d %d\n", a,b,c,d,e );
}
```

After the numbers are sorted, the second largest number is `d`.

Note that if you can't use subroutines and/or pointers, then just copy the body of the `swap` function and paste it into `main` nine times. Then change the letters as needed. Have fun with that.

Comment: Do you really need to sort all the numbers? I don't think so.

Comment: @SauravSahu True, you can reduce the number of calls to `swap` since you only care about the top two numbers. Using a bubble sort technique, you can certainly get the top two numbers with 7 swaps. Can you do it with less? I leave that as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: @user3386109 Thank you so much! Actually I used your idea of sorting. It works as it should, now I will try to reduce the number of `swap` s. Probably would be hard to figure out this idea by my own, thanx!

Answer (score 0):

Initialize two variables: highest and secondHighest with INT_MIN

Do these for all elements:

Secondhighest = max(a[i] , secondhighest)

Highest < second Highest ? swap them : do_nothing

TC : O(N)