# Trying if "?:" conditional block can be made simpler

Tags: c

I was asked if I could write a code to find the biggest of the five numbers, rather than going with the conventional `if...else` (can't use `switch` or traversal - restricted) I decided to use compact version but IMO I found it verbose and confusing (tried it on three numbers first):

```
 #include<stdio.h>

 int main(void)
 {
     int a[3]={9,5,13};
     printf("Biggest No. is: %d\n",(a[0]>
                                         (a[1]>a[2]?a[1]:a[2])?a[0]:
                                                                    (a[1]>a[2]?a[1]:a[2])));
     return 0;
 }
```

Now doing this thing with this method for five numbers seems disastrous, is there any way it can be made simpler (by using this compact method of `?:` only) as writing the expression which acts as a **condition** and writing it again as a **result** seems too much?

Or should I go with the conventional `if ... else` block?

**Found a thing:** To use macro for one expression and use that macro as condition and result for another comparison.

Comment: I think you should make a loop, not a --simple-- `if else` block

Comment: Yup, use `if ... else`, or use a [sorting network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39673059), and take the last value.

Comment: In my opinion a code with if else block is much easier to read and maintain.

Comment: Since you can traverse (iterate) then make a recursive function max with the prototype: `int max(int *nums, int len)`.

Comment: @andlrc Can't try anything apart from `if-else`.

Comment: If you can use STL algorithm, take a look at the `qsort()` function provided by stdlib.h, provide a comparison function for integers, sort the data, and take the first (or last) element of the sorted array (ie: [SO ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1788048/5847906). The benefit is that you can use a bigger array without too much modifications of your code.

Comment: If you can only use if else, then I would rather use that than a nested barely readable set of conditional operators

Comment: @mdewit Mentioned the solution in question.

Comment: `?:` really shouldn't be used for complex cases like this, as you say it quickly turns unreadable. The sane solution is to use a loop to check every item, or alternatively sort the data. Everything else is nonsense and not worth spending time pondering about.

Comment: A loop is the way to go. You do not sacrifice clarity using a loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use nested macros to break down the logic.

```
#define MAX2(a,b)       (a)>(b)?(a):(b)
#define MAX3(a,b,c)     (a)>(b)? MAX2(a,c): MAX2(b,c)
#define MAX4(a,b,c,d)   (a)>(b)? MAX3(a,c,d): MAX3(b,c,d)
#define MAX5(a,b,c,d,e) (a)>(b)? MAX4(a,c,d,e): MAX4(b,c,d,e)
```

Comment: I have already mentioned thiis one in my question as a solution, but thanks - this is the only way it seems.

Comment: I'm rendered speechless:(

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
int main(){

    int a[3]={9,5,13};

    int arr1[] = { a[0], a[1] };
    int arr2[] = { arr1[ a[0] < a[1] ], a[2] };

    printf("max is %d\n", arr2[ arr2[0] < a[2] ]);
}
```

I tried a few cases, seemed to work.